# Non-solvable polynomial over a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, galois-theory, formal-power-series

I am trying to find a good candidate for a non-solvable quadratic polynomial $f(x)=a(z)x^2+b(z)x+c(z)$ over the PID, $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$, of formal power series $a(z),b(z),c(z)$ with complex coefficients. I somehow thought that I can try to make $f$ irreducible, but I seem to get stuck since it seems solvability of polynomials only make sense over a field. Is it possible to somehow relate this polynomial with anything familiar, since the coefficients $a(z),b(z),c(z)$ of $f$ are rather unwieldy.

Comment: How does an unsolvable polynomial differ from an irreducible polynomial?

Comment: When you say non-solvable, do you mean no roots in $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$? In which case isn't it the same as irreducible?

Comment: I mean no roots in $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$, so yes I guess if $f$ can be made irreducible that should work.

Comment: $x^2-z$ should work...

Comment: @mercio, why should it work? That is why is it irreducible as a polynomial?

Comment: It’s irreducible by Eisenstein.

Comment: @Lubin But what are the primes in $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$?, and since 1 and -1 are units in $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ how can I find a prime $p(z)$ such that $p(z)$ does not divid $1$, but does divide $-1$?

Comment: $1$ and $-1$ are units, as is every power series with nonzero constant term, and therefore no prime divides either $1$ or $-1$. There is, for all intents and purposes, only one prime, namely $z$. You should make sure that you understand why a power series with nonzero constant term has a reciprocal in $\Bbb C[[z]]$.